# How to make a call from a phone without SIM using a hotspot with SIM?

Tags: calls, wifi-hotspot, sim-card

I would like to use a single SIM by installing a mobile hotspot at home. This mobile hotspot could be a dedicated hotspot device or an older smartphone with hotspot enabled. This hotspot will serve all my devices at home or on the go.

Meanwhile, I would not have a SIM on my main mobile phone (Google Pixel 3A). This means it will not be able to receive or make dial calls.*

Is there a way to enable my main phone to make calls remotely, via Bluetooth or WiFi, using the Hotspot's SIM?

**I was thinking of using my main phone as the hotspot, but it would probably deplete shorten the life of the battery. This is why I would prefer a dedicated hotspot.*

Comment: Theoretically you could run a software on the hotspot phone that acts as a gateway between GSM and SIP (VoIP protocol). On your second phone you could the use a SIP phone app and connect to this server. Unfortunately I don't know a GSOM-SIP gateway software that rund on Andorid.

Comment: Saw some related info on GSM-SIP gateway here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723453/android-as-sip-to-gsm-gateway but it's above my technical understanding. I am hoping that the same system which allows to call from a smartwatch via phone can be used to call from phone A via phone B.